# Popen does not work anymore with apache/wsgi and python 2.7.2?

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

My django application that used to make some shell commands by using python subprocess.Popen does not work anymore since I upgrade to ubuntu to 11.10

To simplify the problem, I put the faulty code into the wsgi script :

```
import os
import sys

from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
p=Popen(['/usr/bin/id'],stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
comm=p.communicate()
print comm,p.returncode

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

If I run this code directly by python, it works :

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.2+
$ python django_wsgi.py 
('uid=1002(www) gid=1002(www) groups=1002(www)\n', '') 0
```

If I run this code by apache (I just put the relevant URL into a browser), in the apache log, I got :

```
[Tue Nov 29 11:34:38 2011] [error] ('', '') -6
```

What is this error '-6' ???

The problem is that with my development server (Ubuntu 10.04, almost the same apache/wsgi version, same apache configuration file, same environment variables, but with python 2.6.5) it works well :

```
[Tue Nov 29 11:29:10 2011] [error] ('uid=1000(www) gid=1000(www) groups=1000(www)\\n', '') 0
```

Do you know why Popen is not work through apache anymore with python 2.7 ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because latest Python 2.7 has a bug in it which causes fork run in sub interpreters to fail.

http://bugs.python.org/issue13156

Presuming only hosting the one WSGI application, force use of the main interpreter rather than a sub interpreter by adding to your Apache configuration:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

Comment: Really thank you a lot, I was stuck and your answer solved my problem :)

Comment: Need a +10 button for this answer!

Comment: The answers says what the workaround is. Force the use of the main interpreter for that web application using the WSGIApplicationGroup directive. That Python bug also has a patch against if which you could also use to patch Python source code and install a new Python installation and use it.

Comment: I think it helps to know that the patch you need is: http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/ee4fe16d9b48