# Pythons subprocess with WSGI + Apache mpm-worker: IOError 4

Tags: python, apache, subprocess, wsgi, worker

I have a strange problem here which solution I can't figure out by searching the net :/

After switching Apache from mpm-prefork to mpm-worker, using subprocess in my (Django) Python WSGI application raises the following exception after hanging for a couple of time:

```
IOError at /
[Errno 4] Interrupted system call
```

The call in question is:

```
out = check_output(['sudo', 'quota', user_id])
```

where check_output is a backport of this function from Python 2.7 while I'm using Python 2.6 from Debian Squeeze repositories.

The processes, in fact, seem to be executed, but die:

```
ps aux | grep quota
root     15378  0.0  0.0  21864  1176 ?        S    02:34   0:00 sudo quota ...SOME_ID...
root     15379  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    02:34   0:00 [quota] <defunct>
```

The Apache configuration is no more than setting the WSGIScriptAlias and some directory directives.

Am I missing the obvious?

Greets
Sebastian

**Solution:**
Turned out to be a [bug](http://gratisoft.us/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=447) in sudo 1.7.4-4 shipped with Debian 6 . Solved by installing the latest 1.8.x .deb from their homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.7.2 has a bug in it which causes fork in sub interpreters to fail. Try setting:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

in Apache configuration for that WSGI application, to force use of main interpreter.

The Python bug report for the underlying issues is:

http://bugs.python.org/issue13156

Comment: Yes I've seen your answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309465/, but as I said I'm running Python 2.6. I thought about this solution earlier, but doesn't this affect the performance of my app and does it solve the problem in 2.6 at all?

Comment: Okay, in my quick scan of question saw Python 2.7 and assumed wrongly. :-)

Comment: BTW, have you tried with a less complicated command than sudo. For example '/bin/echo hi'. IOW, determine if any sub process execution is failing, or whether may be something related to requirements that sudo has for accessing stuff and doing special things. Also work out if you might have SELinux enabled on the system if it is installed.

Comment: In fact, it works using a more simple command like ['echo', 'hello']. It also works on a second virtual machine where quota is not installed and the call therefore fails. It also works if I use ['quota', user_id] without sudo.

Comment: Have you set up sudoers config file to allow user that application runs as under Apache to use sudo for that command?

Comment: As I said, it works with mod-prefork perfectly. If I switch to mod-worker via apt-get, without any other changes, the error occurs.

Comment: Turned out to be a bug in sudo 1.7.4-4 shipped with Debian 6 (http://www.gratisoft.us/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=447). Solved by installing the latest 1.8.x .deb from their homepage.