# subprocesses from apache returning exit code -6 with not stdout or stderr

Tags: apache, git, subprocess, exit-code, git-status

When running "git status" or even "ls" from an apache process, I will frequently get no standard output or error, and an exit status code of -6. Other times, it just works. Any ideas why this is occurring or what it means?

Comment: @Adam Thanks for the quick reply. After further inspection, it appears that all sub-processes being spawned by the main process, whether it be "git status" or "ls," are returning blank with an exit code of -6. The title is unfortunately now misleadingly narrow.

Comment: duplicate of [Popen does not work anymore with apache/wsgi and python 2.7.2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309465/popen-does-not-work-anymore-with-apache-wsgi-and-python-2-7-2)

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a network with a lot of people, you may be running out of available concurrent connections. This assumes you are on Linux when you talk about your remote. The default of 10 concurrent secure collections is not enough if you have lots of simultaneous connections via ssh.

This is explained by git running on your local machine and then needing to access multiple files on the remote to get the picture of what is in the index and the current commit's tree.