# Django/Python convert PDF using shell (os.system/Popen) not working in production

Tags: python, django, apache

I'm using libreoffice on CLI to convert some documents to PDFs within Django.

This is in my view (and also tried in save method on model):

```
outdir = '/'.join([settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'pdf'])
command = ['libreoffice', '--headless', '--convert-to', 'pdf', '-outdir', outdir, form.instance.upload.path]
stdout, stderr = subprocess.Popen(command).communicate()
```

I've also tried the following in place of `subprocess.Popen`:

```
os.system("libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir %s %s" % (outdir, instance.upload.path))
```

Then I check it out:

```
# quick check new file exists                                                                                                                                                
with open("%s/%s.pdf" % (outdir, os.path.splitext(instance.upload.name)[0])): pass
```

When I run them through the website is just doesn't work -- the PDF file isn't generated.

Thing is: **both these methods work** both in my local environment and when the functions that they're in are called from `$ python manage.py shell`

The problem is only in production.

- Django 1.4
- Python 2.7.3
- Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server built:   Feb 13 2012 01:51:50 (Rackspace)

---

Note that I thought I might be experiencing this bug: [Popen does not work anymore with apache/wsgi and python 2.7.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309465/popen-does-not-work-anymore-with-apache-wsgi-and-python-2-7-2) ...

Though Graham's work around as follows (I added this to my `apache2.conf` ) doesn't seem to change anything.

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

My sys admin skills aren't great though and I may have done this wrong, and I'm totally stumped, any advice or directions of other things to try or work-arounds would be appreciated.

Comment: A common debug tool for sys admins is strace.

Answer (score 1):

`mod_wsgi` when spawned from the `apache2` process won't have the `$PATH` defined that you have on your shell, so you should pass `subprocess.Popen` the **absolute** pathname for the `libreoffice` binary, i.e. `/usr/bin/libreoffice`, not just its filename.

Answer (score 0):

You could import the LibreOffice / OpenOffice uno module to Python and and avoid using the command line.  I've been writing up some more complete documentation, which you can download at http://documenthacker.wordpress.com/ (or maybe soon [www.documenthacker.com](http://www.documenthacker.com)).

There is an example in the cookbook section for converting a document to PDF.

Comment: please provide problem solution here instead of linking to the answer