# Django fails to find R when loading RPy2 under virtualenv

Tags: python, django, osx-mountain-lion, virtualenv, rpy2

This is kind of confusing, apologies in advance. I am configuring a new (temporary) internal production web server with the following specs:

OSX 10.8.4 (Mountain Lion), Apache 2.2.25, PostgreSQL 9.2, Python 2.7.5, Django 1.5.2, R 3.0.1, RPy2 2.3.7, virtualenv 1.10.4, virtualenvwrapper 4.1.1, mod_wsgi 3.4

This was set up on a new machine using Homebrew and pip. I removed original, Apple-installed versions of Apache and Postgres before doing the installs. Both Apache and mod_wsgi work. mod_wsgi is installed to run as daemon process.

Virtual hosts is configured in Apache to access django via mod_wsgi and the `wsgi.py` file contains the following lines:

```
import os,sys,site
site.addsitedir('/Users/kaiju/.virtualenvs/nauru_dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

# Activate the virtual environment
# Taken from http://thecodeship.com/deployment/deploy-django-apache-virtualenv-and-mod_wsgi/
activate_env = os.path.expanduser('/Users/kaiju/.virtualenvs/nauru_dev/bin/activate_this.py')
execfile(activate_env,dict(__file__=activate_env))
```

All python packages (including django and RPy2) have been installed using the virtual environment's python site-packages.

R was installed using Homebrew and works fine from the command line or from python interpreter when invoked within the virtual env (most of the time, more later).

`homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist` has been added to `/Library/LaunchDaemons` instead of `~/Library/LaunchAgents` so that it would automatically start when the machine is rebooted. `homebrew.mxcl.postgres.plist` has been added to `~/Library/LaunchAgents` (probably should also move it to `/Library/LaunchDaemons`).

So **here is the problem**. When everything was installed, it worked together fine. To verify everything was cool, I restarted the machine and tested the django application. Apache is running, as is django, but now I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError at /admin/
R_HOME not defined, and no R command in the PATH.
     Request Method:    GET
        Request URL:    http://nauru.xoma.com/admin/
     Django Version:    1.5.2
     Exception Type:    RuntimeError
    Exception Value:    R_HOME not defined, and no R command in the PATH.
    Exception Location: /Users/kaiju/.virtualenvs/nauru_dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py in <module>, line 48
  Python Executable:    /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7
     Python Version:    2.7.5
        Python Path:    ['usr/local/var/django/code/ri',
                         '/usr/local/var/django/code',
                         '/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.9.8-py2.7.egg',
                         '/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4-py2.7.egg',
                         '/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
                         '/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
                         '/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
                         '/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
                         '/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
                         '/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
                         '/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
                         '/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
                         '/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
                         '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages',
                         '/Users/kaiju/.virtualenvs/nauru_dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
                         '/Users/kaiju/.virtualenvs/nauru_dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL']
```

But if I open a terminal window and type

```
sudo apachectl stop
sudo apachectl start
```

When the server comes back, everything works. This does not happen if I use `sudo apachectl restart`, in that case the error remains. What is going on? Too many moving parts for me.

Comment: Try adding sys.path.append(path_to_r_installation) to your settings.py file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it by adding either `sys.path.append('/usr/local/Cellar/R/3.0.1/bin')` or `sys.path.append('/usr/local/Cellar/R/3.0.1/R.framework')` and neither has an impact on the behavior following restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to resolve this issue is to add

`os.environ['R_HOME']='/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.0.1/R.framework/Resources'`

to the beginning of the wsgi.py file that is being used for mod_wsgi / django. It should be added before activating the virtual environment. Any other environ variables should also be added here. So now the wsgi.py file looks like this:

```
import os,sys,site
os.environ["R_HOME"]='/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.0.1/R.framework/Resources'
site.addsitedir('/Users/kaiju/.virtualenvs/nauru_dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

# Activate the virtual environment
# Taken from http://thecodeship.com/deployment/deploy-django-apache-virtualenv-and-mod_wsgi/
activate_env = os.path.expanduser('/Users/kaiju/.virtualenvs/nauru_dev/bin/activate_this.py')
execfile(activate_env,dict(__file__=activate_env))

sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/local/var/django/code')
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/local/var/django/code/ri')

# We defer to a DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE already in the environment. This breaks
# if running multiple sites in the same mod_wsgi process. To fix this, use
# mod_wsgi daemon mode with each site in its own daemon process, or use
# os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "ri.settings"
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE","ri.settings")

# This application object is used by any WSGI server configured to use this
# file. This includes Django's development server, if the WSGI_APPLICATION
# setting points here.
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Many thanks to those who contributed to this discussion!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `sys.path` has little to do with the environment variable PATH, which the one that should be set (along with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` if needed).

I am guessing that Apache is running as a dedicated user (not your own UID for obvious security reasons), and that user does not have R in its path (other security step - by default Apache should not be able to run any executable on your system).

You'll have to either allow Apache to run the system's R, or have an R install only for your server (the later being the better if considering anything beyond a prototype to play with)

Comment: Yes, Apache is a dedicated server. The R.framework location has universal execute permissions `drwxrwxr-x  8 kaiju  admin     272 Sep  6 15:42 R.framework` so I'm pretty sure Apache should be able to run it. I tried actually exporting a `R_HOME` variable in `.bash_profile` for the user, but R actually complained about it and it didn't solve the problem, so I took it out. Maybe I don't quite understand what you are getting at.

Comment: Ah. Then may be something else like... this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309465/popen-does-not-work-anymore-with-apache-wsgi-and-python-2-7-2 (still not fixed, apparently: http://bugs.python.org/issue13156)

Comment: Perhaps. I added the `WSGIApplicationGroup` to the vhosts file just in case, but it does not solve the problem. My python version is 2.7.5, so this bug has been resolved afaik unless it somehow was resurrected. --Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to figure out why the following returns the value 0: https://bitbucket.org/lgautier/rpy2/src/61b61588007220cecd13cb9032c03430e28cee6a/rpy/rinterface/__init__.py?at=version_2.3.x#cl-17  . It does not seem to be a problem specific to rpy2 though.

Comment: I'm sure you are probably right that it is not specifically an rpy2 problem. However we were able to get things to run by adding `os.environ["R_HOME"]='/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.0.1/R.framework/Resources'` to the rpy2 `__init__.py` file. I recognize this is NOT a proper solution, just a band-aid. Seems like a better solution should lie in the mod_wsgi or virtualenv config, just don't know where