# Django and Apache: Create folder on another server in the network

Tags: python, django, apache, directory

I'm currently developing a Django application for internal use which runs on one server (Server 1) in a local network but needs write access to another server (Server 2) when data is saved to the database.

When a new record is saved, Django creates a new directory on the external server (Server 2) with an appropriate foldername. This was working well on the Django testserver which seemed to have access to the entire local network.

I've now successfully deployed my Django application with Apache and mod_wsgi but the folder creation procedure doesn't seems to work any more. I've tried a few things but can't seem to fix it quickly. Any ideas? Can this actually be achieved with Django and Apache?

```
def create_folder(self,request,obj,form, change, serverfolder, templatefolder):

    try:
        source_dir = templatefolder # Replace with path to project folder template
        if not os.path.exists(destination_dir):
            dir_util.copy_tree(source_dir,destination_dir)
            obj.projectfolder = destination_dir
            messages.success(request,"Project folder created on %s" % (serverfolder))
            obj.create_folder = False
            obj.has_folder = True
        else:
            messages.warning(request,"No new project folder created on %s server" % (obj.office.abbreviation))
    except Exception,e:
        messages.warning(request,str(e) + " Error during project folder creation on %s server!" % (obj.office.abbreviation))



def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
         serverfolder = r'\\C-s-002\Projects' #C-s-002 is the external server in the same local network as the server on which Django is running
         templatefolder = r'\\C-s-002\Projects\XXX Project Template'
         self.create_folder(request,obj,form, change, serverfolder, templatefolder)
```

Comment: I can not see the connection to another server (Server 2). What does `serverfolder` contain?

Comment: The connection is not made in the code itself. The Django project is located on C-s-001. When running, it raises an error saying the \\C-s-002\\Projects is not a valid folder

Comment: You are really have to write some code that can connect to another server (via ssh for example) and execute shell commands there.

Answer (score 0):

There are various approaches you can take here, so I will not attempt to exhaust all possibilities:

Option 1: [Call an external command with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python).  This is not specific to Django or Apache.

Option 2: Set up a web service on Server 2 that you can access via API calls to handle the file/directory creation needed by Server 1.  This could be implemented with Django.

Comment: Calling external commands with Django and Apache seems to generate other problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309465/popen-does-not-work-anymore-with-apache-wsgi-and-python-2-7-2  Looks like I'll have to go with the 2nd option